# How to retag when question is about a separate but almost equivalent game/mod?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sorry about the title not being very clear, I can't think of a good way to phrase it. Please feel free to edit it to be more clear.

The Community user recently bumped [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/230230/1459800) (presumably because it doesn't have an accepted answer). I noticed that it is tagged with the [soft-pixel-dungeon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-pixel-dungeon) tag - and it is the only one tagged that way.

For those of you who don't know, there is a game on the Google Play store called Pixel Dungeon whose code was open-sourced. This was the original version of the game. Because the code was released, there have been several different variations of the original released on the play store - Shattered Pixel Dungeon, Remixed Pixel Dungeon, Unleashed Pixel Dungeon... the list goes on and on. Soft Pixel Dungeon is one of these variations.

Since we do have a populated [pixel-dungeon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pixel-dungeon) tag, I am unsure how to handle the tags on this question. My initial feeling would be to retag with the "base" Pixel Dungeon tag and add the [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods) tag. However, since each of these PD variations are technically standalone apps, they might not be considered direct mods. What is the consensus on this situation?

Comment: Are they the same game? What similarities/differences are there?

Comment: All the variations are based off of the same initial source code. I haven't played this "Soft" version specifically, but I have played some of the others, and the gameplay is mostly the same for all of them. They usually just have difficulty tweaks or additions of levels/items/monsters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variations are standalone apps on the store.  The variations tend to add new levels, items and monsters.  I feel this warrants a tag specific to this variation, as already done.

Therefore, there is nothing to do other than add relevant info to the tag itself.